# I seem to have wrong math for marginal independence proof (details in question), can anyone explain where my logic went wrong.

Tags: marginal-probability

I'm not sure but for proofing marginal independence I've came across this stack exchange [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481087/independence-vs-marginal-independence#:%7E:text=As%20Jimmy%20R%20points%20out%2C%20marginal%20independence%20is,variables%20given%20the%20value%20of%20another%20random%20variable), and from there to this [link](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Ecarenini/TEACHING/CPSC322-10/SLIDES/lecture26-2010.pdf), where I found that the condition to hold for 2 variables to be independent marginally is
$P(X \lor Y) = P(X)$
which I assume can be basically translated to the probability of either events X, or Y happening is identical to probability of X happening which doesn't make much sense. Like that would imply that
$P(x) + P(y) - P(x)\times{P(y)} = P(x)$,
which is only possible when
$P(x)\times{P(y)} = P(y)$
which then implies that
$P(x) = 1$
which implies X is certain. So for y to be independent of X, X should be certain? that looks like I've completely messed my math somehow

Comment: You seem to mix $P(X\ or\ Y)$ with $P_Y(X)$. We do not have $P(X\ or Y)=P(X)$ in the case of independent $X$ and $Y$, think for example of two coin tosses : The probability that at least one of the tosses shows "heads" is $\frac{3}{4}$ and not $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Peter thanks, indeed my silly mistake. Thank you for pointing my attention to it. Could you make it an answer so i can  accept it?